# Error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator^'

Tags: c++

> Error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'float' to binary 'operator^'

Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
  int a,w;
  float P,M,y,i,n;
  for(a=1;a=2;)
  {
    printf("Enter the value of Pricipal \n");
    scanf("%f",&P);
    printf("Enter the value of yearly interest rate \n");
    scanf("%f",&y);
    i=y/12;
    printf("Enter Term in years \n");
    scanf("%d",&w);
    n=w*12;
    M=(P*i*((1+i)^n))/(((1+i)^n)-1);
    printf("Monthly Payment is %f \n",M);
  } 
}
```

Comment: you have something like `1.2^2.0` in your code?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: are you looking for [`pow`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) ?

Comment: Although, IMHO the question is answerable solely on the error.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker: well, someone's feeling helpful! I've pinched that.

Comment: Not at all, but I will upvote an answer of yours.

Comment: Look up language features that you use.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As what you have written is basically C if you want to really learn C++ then it sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: @Bathsheba : that's ok - upvoted yours instead ;)

Answer (score 4):

The arguments to the XOR operator `^` must be integral types in C++.

Note that `std::pow` is used for exponentation in C++.